# GradientDrawable change angle programmatically

Tags: android

I have following xml for GradientDrawable. How can I change the angle programmatically?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:type="linear" 
       android:angle="45" 
       android:startColor="#FF0000" 
       android:endColor="#00FF00" />
</shape>
```

Comment: GradientDrawable does have a setOrientation(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation) I don't know if this would suit your needs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GradientDrawable has a method called: `.setOrientation(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation)`, you can change the orientation of a gradient with this. You need to inflate the XML as GradientDrawable.

Comment: It has only very specific constant values, while the `angle` is actually a float that you can set any degree you want, no?

Comment: I don't think GradientDrawable providers a setAngle(), so you can't set it programatically.

Comment: Seems the XML has a restriction about it that matches the one of setOrientation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:angle "Must be a multiple of 45 in the range [0, 315]." . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.Orientation.html . So they are actually the same, yet with different name for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
GradientDrawable appTheme = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR, colors);
```